# csv.writing formating from beautifulsoup table/row

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, beautifulsoup

So i have a working code that pulls data from 30 websites on a domain.

```
with open("c:\source\list.csv") as f:
  for row in csv.reader(f):
    for url in row:
      r = requests.get(url)
      soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
      tables = soup.find('table', attrs={"class": "hpui-standardHrGrid-table"})
      for rows in tables.find_all('tr', {'releasetype': 'Current_Releases'})[0::1]:
        item = []
        for val in rows.find_all('td'):
          item.append(val.text.strip())
      with open('c:\source\output_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow({url})
        writer.writerows(item)
```

When I open the CSV file, I see each character taken from the 'Item' variable is stored in its own cell. I can't seem to find out what the heck is doing this and how to fix it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I've tried removing the 'strip' from 'item.append(val.text.strip()) to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by changing

```
    writer.writerows(item)
```

to

```
    writer.writerow(item)
```